# Ship third party dependenies along with aar file

Tags: android, android-library, aar

I have a `flavour based library module` and i would like to distriubte `aar` file to clients , each `flavour` have client specific changes and configs. My `library module` is using some thrid party libraries like some custom `progress dialogs` etc , what's happening currently is that whenever i create `aar` file and use it in any `application` it says `could not find some source` and the source which its pointing out is the one from 3rd party libraries but whenever i add all the `dependencies` in that `application` all errors are GONE, so my question is how can i ship those dpendencies along with aar or any other best solution .

just to make it clear what i am receving as errors are like

```
account.xml:121: error: attribute cardBackgroundColor (aka com.my.app:cardBackgroundColor) not found
```

and cardBackgroundColor is a property of CardVeiw

> NOTE: i have added `aar` as `flatDir`

Comment: a solution which comes in my mind is to provide pom.xml along with aar .. you can say it would be kinda worst hack :P